# Materialize no funciona en ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize, rubygems

Estoy intentando personalizar un diseño pero al agregar archivos de *materialize* en el código html no me sale nada, es como si no leyera el *materialize*.

Ya hice las respectivas modificaciones a los archivos necesarios:

application.cscc

```
@import "materialize";
```

aplication.js

```
//= require materialize-sprockets
```

Tengo instaladas las gemas `jquery-turbolinks` y `materialize-sass`, no sé que pueda ser.

Por favor agradezco su ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código de la vista en la que estás utilizando *materialize* y no funciona? En cuanto a los archivos modificados, supongo que fue error de dedo, pero deben ser **application.scss** y **application.js**.

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/161469/edit) y agregar el código de la vista ahí? ¿Reiniciaste tu aplicación después de modificar los archivos necesarios?